# Push to nested array using pymongo (python, mongodb)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, push

I'm having some difficulty finding the right element inside 'courses' to push a new array of elements 'course_content'.

What I have:

```
{
  '_id': ObjectId('65759a25ccee59d54778968e'),
  'user_email': 'user@gmail.com',
  'password': 'password123',
  'courses': [
    {
      'course_name': 'great course',
      'course_info': 'Course info great course'
    },
    {
      'course_name': 'bad course',
      'course_info': 'Course info bad course'
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want:

```
{
  '_id': ObjectId('65759a25ccee59d54778968e'),
  'user_email': 'user@gmail.com',
  'password': 'password123',
  'courses': [
    {
      'course_name': 'great course',
      'course_info': 'Course info great course'
      'course_content: [{summary: "the quick brown fox",
                        info:"this is from a particular source"
                       }]
    },
    {
      'course_name': 'bad course',
      'course_info': 'Course info bad course'
    }
  ]
}
```

Subsequently, I would like to add to the course_content as below:

```
{
  '_id': ObjectId('65759a25ccee59d54778968e'),
  'user_email': 'user@gmail.com',
  'password': 'password123',
  'courses': [
    {
      'course_name': 'great course',
      'course_info': 'Course info great course'
      'course_content: [{summary: "the quick brown fox",
                        info:"this is from a particular source"
                       },
                        {summary: "jumps over the lazy",
                        info:"this a great story"
                       },
                       {summary: "dogs",
                        info:"dogs are cool"
                       }]
    },
    {
      'course_name': 'bad course',
      'course_info': 'Course info bad course'
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to find what I want to update.

```
collection.find_one(
            {'_id': ObjectId(session_document_id)},
            {'courses': {'$elemMatch': {'course_name': 'great course'}}}
        )
```

However, I'm unable to push to it.

```
collection.update_one(
            {'_id': ObjectId(session_document_id)},
            {'courses': {'$elemMatch': {'course_name': 'great course'}}},
            {'$push': {'courses.$.course_name':{summary: "the quick brown fox",
                        info:"this is from a particular source"
                       }}}
        )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Update 1:
Tried the following

```
collection.update_one(
{"courses.course_name": course_name},
{"$push": {"courses.$[course].course_content": {"$each": [content]}}},
{"arrayFilters": [{"courses.course_name": course_name}],
"multi": True
})
```

But received the following error:

```
TypeError}TypeError("upsert must be True or False, was: upsert={'arrayFilters': [{'courses.course_name': 'great course'}], 'multi': True}")
```

Adding upsert gave me the error:

```
{TypeError}TypeError("Collection.update_one() got multiple values for argument 'upsert'")
```

Removing `'multi':True` did not result in any change with regards to the errors I am getting

---

Update 2
The following code runs but seems to push 'content' to every element in 'course_content':

```
collection.update_one(
{"courses.course_name": course_name},
{"$push": {"courses.$[].course_content": content}}, upsert=True)
```

---

Update 3

This bit of code seems to be working. Thanks all for all your advice and guidance.

```
collection.find_one_and_update(
filter ={'_id': ObjectId('6576576759045839397565bd'), "courses.course_name": course_name},
update={"$push": {"courses.$.course_content": content}}, upsert=True)
```

Comment: Using [`pymongo`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one), it may be better to be explicit about the calling arguments.  If you use, `collection.update_one(filter ={'_id': ObjectId(session_document_id), "courses.course_name": course_name}, update={"$push": {"courses.$[course].course_content": {"$each": [content]}}}, array_filters=[{"courses.course_name": course_name}])`, does that work?

Comment: `{WriteError}WriteError('No array filter found for identifier \'course_name\' in path \'courses.$[course_name].course_content\', full error...e\': 2, \'errmsg\': "No array filter found for identifier \'course_name\' in path \'courses.$[course_name].course_content\'"}')`

Comment: Oops, typo.  How about `collection.update_one(filter ={'_id': ObjectId(session_document_id), "courses.course_name": course_name}, update={"$push": {"courses.$[course].course_content": {"$each": [content]}}}, array_filters=[{"course.course_name": course_name}])`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `arrayFilters` to locate the course entry and `$push` to the array with `$each`.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "courses.course_name": "great course"
},
{
  "$push": {
    "courses.$[course].course_content": {
      "$each": [
        {
          "summary": "the quick brown fox",
          "info": "this is from a particular source"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "course.course_name": "great course"
    }
  ],
  "multi": true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0YUUKsjml7A)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the questions @ray. However, I'm using a more recent version of pymongo where the "update" function doesn't exist. Trying the following:

`collection.update_one(
    {"courses.course_name": course_name},
    {"$push": {"courses.$[course].course_content": {"$each": [content]}}},
    {"arrayFilters": [{"courses.course_name": course_name}],
    "multi": True
    })`

gives me an error:
`{TypeError}TypeError("upsert must be True or False, was: upsert={'arrayFilters': [{'courses.course_name': 'great course'}], 'multi': True}")`

Comment: adding upsert gives me the error:
`{TypeError}TypeError("Collection.update_one() got multiple values for argument 'upsert'")`

Comment: @DiscoStu You don't need `multi: true` for your case. It is just there in my answer for working around some restriction in playground. Can you try again without `multi: true`?

Comment: Thanks @Ray. I've tried removing `multi:true` as you suggested but it gives me an error asking me to add `upsert=True or False`. When I add upsert, I get the same error as above suggesting that there are multiple values for argument 'upsert'.

Comment: @DiscoStu Can you [edit] your question to include the latest version of code you are having right now? It is quite messy to read in comments.